# Deleting a node in Linked List in python

Tags: python, search, linked-list

To delete a node in a linked list, what is wrong with this implementation?:

```
def delete(self, val):
    tmp = self.head
    prev = None
    while tmp: 
        if val == tmp.data:
            self.size -= 1
            if prev==None: 
                self.head = self.head.next 
            else:
                prev.next = tmp.next 
        else:
            prev = tmp
            tmp = tmp.next
```

All the guides I've looked at say it  should be:

```
def delete(self, data):
    tmp = self.head
    prev = None
    found = False 
    while tmp and not found:
        if data == tmp.data:
            found = True
        else:
            prev = tmp
            tmp = tmp.next
    if found:
        self.size -= 1
        if prev == None:
            self.head = self.head.next
        else:
            prev.next = tmp.next
```

but **I can't figure out why the *found* is needed**. Why is the found necessary? Why is this implementation more correct?

Additionally, I have the same trouble with *search*:

My implementation is:

```
def __contains__(self, data):
    tmp = self.head
    while tmp:
        if data == tmp.data:
            return True 
        else: 
            tmp = tmp.next
    return False
```

but the correct implementation is:

```
def __contains__(self, data):
        tmp = self.head
        found = False
        while tmp and not found:
            if data == tmp.data:
                found = True
            else: 
                tmp = tmp.next
        return found
```

Comment: Hmm your delete looks fine. Is it not working correctly? Essentially you just cut the code out of the if and placed it in if the condition is true which is fine. Plus i think the guide implementation if found should be tabbed one more time. Looks wrong

Comment: found is used to exit the loop at a certain node.

Comment: @CurlyJoe: Ohh, that makes tons of sense. What about for **search** though? For search, I exit too -- I'm sure my implementation is better because it's more concise, but I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The `delete`s are identical as long as data is unique. So it is in general better, do separate looping through the list, from working on elements. It is more readable, and less nested. It would be still better, to give an error, if `data` is not found:

```
def delete(self, data):
    tmp = self.head
    prev = None
    while tmp:
        if data == tmp.data:
            break
        prev = tmp
        tmp = tmp.next
    else:
        raise ValueError('data not found')
    self.size -= 1
    if prev is None:
        self.head = tmp.next
    else:
        prev.next = tmp.next
```

Comment: @thought of `head.next` and `prev.next`, but this was non-sense.